# Prevent Backbone set validates after save

Tags: ajax, validation, backbone.js, save, set

I'm trying to do client side validation on a Backbone model that involves an ajax call to the server in order to determine if the new entry is a duplicate of an existing one (determined by matching a title). Here's the steps

1. Check if model is new.
2. If new, AJAX GET from `validate()` to see if model exists already (by title).
3. If response = duplicate set status invalid, if not proceed with `save()`

The problem Im having is that Backbone is doing the following.

1. save()
2. validate() : *GET returns not duplicate*
3. validation passed, set()
4. validate() : **GET returns duplicate**

My question is about how to prevent that second `validate()` from firing on the set because it triggers another GET request and I get an error response even though technically Im "done" saving.

To keep this short here is the validate, and save calls

```js
List = Backbone.Model.extend({

idAttribute: "_id",

urlRoot: '/api/lists',
...

validate: function(attrs) {
    // if we are editing don't bother with this (for now)
    if (this.isNew()) {

        // see if this title already exists
        var result = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/lists/" + this.generateTitleKey(attrs.title),
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                result = data;
            }
        });

        if(result.length > 0) {
                return {
                    field: "title",
                    errMsg: "You already have this list"
                };
        }
    }
}
});


ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

...

save: function() {

    var _self = this;
    var fields = {
        title: _self.$el.find('input[name="new-list-name"]').val()
    }

    _self.resetErrors();

    _self.model.save(fields, {
        wait: true,
        silent: true,
        success: function(model, res) {
            if(res.err) {
                // add UI error
            } else {
                new app.View({ model: _self.model });
                _self.close();
            }
        },
        error: function(model, res) {
            console.log('inside error');
        }
    })
}
});

app.post('/api/lists', function(req, res){

var list = new ListModel({
    titleKey: generateTitleKey(req.body.title),
    title: req.body.title
});

return list.save(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        return res.send(list);
    } else {
        return res.status(409).send(JSON.stringify({
            err: true,
            errSrc: "list",
            errType: "insert",
            errMsg: "That's already a list!"
        }));
    }
});
});
```

silent: true doesnt seem to be working for me, save() and set() both trigger validate().

I know there are a number of approaches to doing error handling for validation but I'm purposely trying to use the native valide method that a backbone Model has, and its been working great UNTIL I try to use it with the ajax call. Im so close here I can taste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the model not to validate a set with `model.set('something', true, { validate: false });`. FYI you can do the same in the `.save` options hash if you need to.

What are you setting anyway? Normally the server response is the attributes you want to save on the client model so maybe you can return what you need on that and avoid calling set.

Comment: If I pass validate: false to save() wont it skip the initial validation prior to pushing to server too? Thing is I'm not calling set myself. Save() is calling Set() after it successfully stores on server. Im not even calling Set() directly, im ONLY calling save(fields, { opts }). I overwrote backbones set() and save() to console log when each is triggered and Set() is being auto-called when save() succeeds.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes save will call set that is expected - you are supposed to return all the attributes the model is supposed to set on itself. Looking at your code again suggests the problem is that `if (this.isNew()) {` is not working properly, the second time it should not be new - my guess is that you are not returning an ID when you save the model or the id is not being mapped (if it's not called 'id' you need to tell Backbone that).

Comment: Good, ok, so at least I'm right in the save() -> set() flow. I've updated my code to show what I'm assigning the Model `id` to and what my server returns (node.js, mongoose). If the return syntax from the API looks correct just let me know and I'll go back to debugging whats inside. I want to make sure I'm executing the API save and returning variables correctly.

Comment: Curious. If Im trying to set() the model (with a valid ID) and validate() happens BEFORE a set() is allowed, wouldn't isNew() still technically be true since the _id hasn't been assigned yet?

Answer (score 1):

Dominic Tobias led me to the right answer.

`isNew()` wont work as a check because on the response from the server, the model is validated BEFORE it's set, so isNew() is still technically true at the time of validation for the post save() set. I changed the check in validate() to `if(attrs._id)` and everything works.